# How can I rotate a table that requires a group by without using pivot and case when in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, adventureworks

This is the code I'm trying to run

```
select min(sod.ModifiedDate) as [ModifiedDate]
    ,Bikes = (select sum(LineTotal) from SalesOrderDetail where max(ProductCategoryName) = 'Bikes' and ModifiedDate = sod.ModifiedDatee)
    ,Components = (select sum(LineTotal) from SalesOrderDetail where max(ProductCategoryName) = 'Components' and ModifiedDate = sod.ModifiedDate)
    ,Clothing = (select sum(LineTotal) from SalesOrderDetail where max(ProductCategoryName) = 'Clothing' and ModifiedDate = sod.ModifiedDate )
    ,Accessories = (select sum(LineTotal) from SalesOrderDetail where max(ProductCategoryName) = 'Accessories' and ModifiedDate = sod.ModifiedDate )

from SalesOrderDetail sod
inner join product p on p.ProductID = sod.ProductID
inner join ProductSubcategory ps on ps.ProductSubcategoryID = p.ProductSubcategoryID
inner join ProductCategory pc on pc.ProductCategoryID = ps.ProductCategoryID

group by ProductCategoryName
    ,sod.ModifiedDate
    ,datepart(year, sod.ModifiedDate) 
    ,datepart(month, sod.ModifiedDate) 
    ,datepart(day, sod.ModifiedDate)        

order by datepart(year, sod.ModifiedDate) 
    ,datepart(month, sod.ModifiedDate) 
    ,datepart(day, sod.ModifiedDate)
```

I can't figure out how to make it so it splits the LineTotal into the four ProductNameCategory like this: (expected result)

| ModifiedDate | Bikes | Components | Clothing | Accessories |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2005-07-01 00:00:00.000 | 467709.136900 | 31525.960400 | 2875.153600 | 1695.666000 |
| 2005-07-02 00:00:00.000 | 13931.520000 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2005-07-03 00:00:00.000 | 15012.178200 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2005-07-04 00:00:00.000 | 7156.540000 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2005-07-05 00:00:00.000 | 15012.178200 | NULL | NULL | NULL |

All I get is this, it adds all the lineTotal for a given date regardless of ProductCategoryName and then puts the sum in Components, except when the only thing there is that day is Bikes, then he puts it in Bikes.

| ModifiedDate | Bikes | Components | Clothing | Accessories |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2005-07-01 00:00:00.000 | NULL | 503805.916900 | NULL | NULL |
| 2005-07-02 00:00:00.000 | 13931.520000 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2005-07-03 00:00:00.000 | 15012.178200 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2005-07-04 00:00:00.000 | 7156.540000 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2005-07-05 00:00:00.000 | 15012.178200 | NULL | NULL | NULL |

How can I make it look like the expected result without Pivot and case when?  I need to get the results showed here using four different methods to then test performance and I already used pivot and case when. I'm trying to use this method I found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-design/rotate-table  for this specific query

Comment: your writing style is very different to mine so I might be misunderstanding what this is meant to be doing so this might not help. Why are you using max(ProductCategoryName) in your subqueries? Also why use ISNULL to then return NULL

Comment: `without using pivot and case` -> can you explain why? You want to pivot data but you don't want to use the two most common ways to pivot data, if you want meaningful answers you're probably going to need to explain that a little more.

Comment: Also what table does `ProductCategoryName` come from? You never use an alias on it and I wonder if one of the joins here is unnecessary.

Comment: @Rhythm Was a Lurker I need to get the results showed here using four different methods to then test performance and I already used pivot and case when. I'm trying to use this method I found [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-design/rotate-table) for this specific query.

Comment: @RickyTillson
That is the problem if I don't put the max I get the "not in aggregate or group by" error, but if I put in group by it splits each day into four different lines, when it should be split into 4 different columns. Also this specific query is based on something I found online that I added in the question but you're right the isnull is useless here, I removed it

Comment: I can tell you without even trying it that it isn't normally going to be possible for that approach to be _faster_, since it has to access the table n times instead of once, unless there's some index especially tailored to allow for seeks on those narrow ranges. In fact that's the problem PIVOT and MAX(CASE) are meant to solve - being able to perform those aggregates in a single pass of the table or range rather than multiple.

Comment: @Rhythm Was a Lurker
 you're right, that's propably even the point of the exercise, but for now performance doesn't really matter, as long as long as I get the expected results.  So would you know why  the LineTotal split up between their respective ProductCategoryName? Why does it display the LineTotal that is wronfully added all together in the "Components" column if bike is the first column to be calculated? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it without `PIVOT` or `CASE`, but it's really ugly as a result, even after pulling some of the joins and aggregations out of the main query:

```
WITH ProductMeta AS 
(
  SELECT p.ProductID, CatName = pc.Name
  FROM Production.Product AS p
  INNER JOIN Production.ProductSubcategory ps 
    on ps.ProductSubcategoryID = p.ProductSubcategoryID
  INNER JOIN Production.ProductCategory pc 
    on pc.ProductCategoryID = ps.ProductCategoryID
  WHERE pc.Name IN (N'Bikes',N'Components',N'Clothing',N'Accessories')
), Agg AS
(
  SELECT date = CONVERT(date, sod.ModifiedDate), 
    pm.CatName, 
    LineTotal = SUM(LineTotal)
  FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail sod
  INNER JOIN ProductMeta AS pm ON sod.ProductID = pm.ProductID
  GROUP BY CONVERT(date, sod.ModifiedDate), pm.CatName
)
SELECT a.date
    ,Bikes       = (SELECT SUM(LineTotal) FROM Agg 
                    WHERE date = a.date AND CatName = 'Bikes')
    ,Components  = (SELECT SUM(LineTotal) FROM Agg 
                    WHERE date = a.date AND CatName = 'Components')
    ,Clothing    = (SELECT SUM(LineTotal) FROM Agg 
                    WHERE date = a.date AND CatName = 'Clothing')
    ,Accessories = (SELECT SUM(LineTotal) FROM Agg 
                    WHERE date = a.date AND CatName = 'Accessories')
FROM Agg AS a
GROUP BY a.date;
```

Comment: Good solution. Complets in 0.218s on my system.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with just modifying your code. After downloading AdventureWorks, I validated this runs and the output matches your table above (minus the superfluous 00:00:00 times);

```
select DISTINCT CAST(sod.ModifiedDate as date) as [ModifiedDate]
    , Bikes = (
        select sum(LineTotal) 
        from Sales.SalesOrderDetail as sod2
            inner join production.product p on p.ProductID = sod2.ProductID
            inner join production.ProductSubcategory ps on ps.ProductSubcategoryID = p.ProductSubcategoryID
            inner join production.ProductCategory pc on pc.ProductCategoryID = ps.ProductCategoryID
        where pc.[Name] = 'Bikes' 
            and CAST(sod2.ModifiedDate as date) = CAST(sod.ModifiedDate as date)
      )
    , Components = (
        select sum(LineTotal) 
        from Sales.SalesOrderDetail as sod2
            inner join production.product p on p.ProductID = sod2.ProductID
            inner join production.ProductSubcategory ps on ps.ProductSubcategoryID = p.ProductSubcategoryID
            inner join production.ProductCategory pc on pc.ProductCategoryID = ps.ProductCategoryID
        where pc.[Name] = 'Components' 
            and CAST(sod2.ModifiedDate as date) = CAST(sod.ModifiedDate as date)
    )
    , Clothing = (
        select sum(LineTotal) 
        from Sales.SalesOrderDetail as sod2
            inner join production.product p on p.ProductID = sod2.ProductID
            inner join production.ProductSubcategory ps on ps.ProductSubcategoryID = p.ProductSubcategoryID
            inner join production.ProductCategory pc on pc.ProductCategoryID = ps.ProductCategoryID
        where pc.[Name] = 'Clothing' 
            and CAST(sod2.ModifiedDate as date) = CAST(sod.ModifiedDate as date)
    )
    , Accessories = (
        select sum(LineTotal) 
        from Sales.SalesOrderDetail  as sod2
            inner join production.product p on p.ProductID = sod2.ProductID
            inner join production.ProductSubcategory ps on ps.ProductSubcategoryID = p.ProductSubcategoryID
            inner join production.ProductCategory pc on pc.ProductCategoryID = ps.ProductCategoryID
        where pc.[Name] = 'Accessories' 
            and CAST(sod2.ModifiedDate as date) = CAST(sod.ModifiedDate as date)
    )

from Sales.SalesOrderDetail sod
order by CAST(sod.modifiedDate as date)
```

Sample results:

[image]

EDIT:
This query completes in less than 0.359 seconds.

```
WITH prelim as (
    select sod2.LineTotal, sod2.ModifiedDate, pc.Name as ProductCategoryName 
    from Sales.SalesOrderDetail as sod2
        inner join production.product p on p.ProductID = sod2.ProductID
        inner join production.ProductSubcategory ps on ps.ProductSubcategoryID = p.ProductSubcategoryID
        inner join production.ProductCategory pc on pc.ProductCategoryID = ps.ProductCategoryID
)
select DISTINCT CAST(sod.ModifiedDate as date) as [ModifiedDate]
    , Bikes = (
        SELECT SUM(LineTotal)
        FROM prelim as p
        WHERE p.ModifiedDate = sod.ModifiedDate
            AND p.ProductCategoryName = 'Bikes'
      )
    , Components = (
        SELECT SUM(LineTotal)
        FROM prelim as p
        WHERE p.ModifiedDate = sod.ModifiedDate
            AND p.ProductCategoryName = 'Components' 
    )
    , Clothing = (
        SELECT SUM(LineTotal)
        FROM prelim as p
        WHERE p.ModifiedDate = sod.ModifiedDate
            AND p.ProductCategoryName = 'Clothing' 
    )
    , Accessories = (
        SELECT SUM(LineTotal)
        FROM prelim as p
        WHERE p.ModifiedDate = sod.ModifiedDate
            AND p.ProductCategoryName = 'Accessories' 
    )

from Sales.SalesOrderDetail sod
order by CAST(sod.modifiedDate as date)
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the main problem of why the LineTotal splits up between their respective ProductCategoryName. Also using so many casts makes a query that took 0:00 sec in a query that takes 1:27 min. The joins are because the ProductCategoryName column is only in ProductCategory and I need to group by the ModifiedDate in SalesOrderDetail. Also with this answer the modified date splits into four different lines for a given day, but I need one line per day.

Comment: Show us a few rows of each table for better help. The modified query I posted will group by the ModifiedDate. It should only return one row for each date. Sounds like you need to add back the joins to ProductCategory in each subquery, not the main `SELECT`. see edited query above.

Comment: Also I don't really know how to give sample data, but it's based on adventureworks, the database created by Microsoft so it's available to download for free (https://github.com/microsoft/sql-server-samples/tree/master/samples/databases/adventure-works)

Comment: I just downloaded AdventureWorks2012. I got the query working and edited my answer above. Query completes in 17s. There is one row per date with a subtotal for each ProductCategory.Name.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand why the cast was required for your solution. By doing so you remove the need for a group by which lets you add the join in the subqueries

Comment: Last edit... the updated query with a CTE completes in under a second.